# Where is the repository "Standards" of PHP CodeSniffer with the sonar PHP plugin?

Tags: php, sonarqube, extend, rules, phpcodesniffer

I have installed [SonarQube™](http://www.sonarqube.org/) and the [PHP Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin).

I want to add a new CodeSniffer rule, like it's indicated in http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Custom+Coding+Rules.

However, I can't find the location of the "Standard" repository wich contains existing rules (PEAR, Squiz, Generic...). So I don't know where I have to add my new file corresponding to the xml rule I have defined in the sonar settings.

Maybe I've missed something but I looked in every folder in the PHP plugin and didn't find this "Standard" folder. I even extracted content from the .jar files of the plugin and even looked in the rest of my disk in case of the code sniffer repository were somewhere else.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard folder belongs to PHP_CodeSniffer not to SonorCube. Its located inside the PHP_Codesniffer installation (which depends on how you installed PHP_CodeSniffer on your machine). If you found it the Standards folder is located under

```
PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeSniffer/Standards/
```

My guess is that you want execute a rule inside SonarCube. I don't know SonarCube but I am sure you need to configure the path to PHP_CodeSniffer somewhere. After done that its like it says in the docu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>

  <rule key="PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.TagIndent" priority="MAJOR">
    <!-- name, configKey, description are mandatory -->
    <name>Tag comment incorrectly indented</name>
    <configKey>TAG_INDENT</configKey>
    <description>@category tag comment incorrectly indented</description>
  </rule>

  <rule key="...>
    ...
  </rule>

</rules>
```

With:

```
       PEAR           Commenting         FileComment                   TagIndent
<standard_folder>.<sniff_subfolder>.<sniff_file_without_sniff_suffix>.<error_name>
```

The way to go is:

1. Install PHP_Codesniffer (via Composer, Pear or plain from Github) [1]
2. Set the path to PHP_Codesniffer inside SonarCube
3. Configure the rules

[1] https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Comment: But the problem is I didn't install codesniffer separately, it was included with the sonar php plugin package. And this plugin doesn't use codesniffer only, other rules are checked to analyze php projects. That's why it seemed more useful to use this plugin than to install other components somewhere else. Therefore, I don't completely understand the sonar documentation as I can't find the Standard codesniffer folder.

Comment: As you can see here [1], the PHP_CodeSniffer and other tools are included as PHAR files. This is a compressed file with all PHP files in it. But you can also see that its recommend to install your own external versions of the programs via PEAR.

[1] http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+PHP+Environment

Comment: Yes, that's just what I was thinking ten minutes ago, so I've intented to install PHP code sniffer separately, after installing pear (I didn't want to install all that on my server but it seems I have no choice if I want to edit these codesniffer rules). Thanks

Comment: So I installed PHP_code_sniffer. But now, even setting config like this : sonar.phpCodeSniffer.analyzeOnly=true and sonar.phpCodeSniffer.reportPath=myfile.xml (I tried setting these parameters directly on my sonar project properties, as in the sonar global properties and as by define it on the interface), sonar doesn't retrieve these results from the xml file, no error/warning appears on sonar dashboard although there are errors in the xml file. And it seems someone else encountered the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582218/sonar-runner-not-creating-database-entries.

Comment: Are you sure, that phpcs is executed?

Comment: Yes, it's executed, I can see a line with "CodeSniffer sensor..." during the sonar process. Anyway, I abandonned the idea of reuse an existing xml file. And that's at this time that I could have seen that sonar uses CodeSniffer found on the server rather than executing a "php phpcs.phar" command. So my problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but the latest Sonar uses its own Rule Engine now, so no more dependency on CodeSniffer. For me, it means I can no longer run my Symfony2 code standards checker on Sonar, sad...

Answer (score -1):

1. Get the rules (PSR1, PSR2, or your own) from here:
   http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Custom+Coding+Rules
2. Copy and paste them as described here into the Codesniffer Plugin Custom Rules:
   http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Custom+Coding+Rules
3. Download and restore the profiles as described in 1

Works fine with SonarQube 4.1.1